# Configure sender mail address in laravel .env file

Tags: laravel-5

Im using laravel 5.6 application to develope the project. In that project i have to send mail to the user. so i want to configure the sender mail address in `env` and `mail.php` file.

If it is for gmail then i will use like below in env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=vino@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=feaeda91d
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

Then in my mail.php:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
```

But im not using gmails i want to use my office email address **(vino123@xxx.in)** and the domain name is **mail.xxx.in** so i dont know how to configure **host**, **driver** and **port** values in my `env` and `mail.php` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you must ask all Informations related the Mail Server which is responsible for sending on receiving email, of you office domain to Who is responsible for managing that server.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
// The server IP address or domaine name of the mail server
MAIL_HOST=your_ofice_domaine_name.in
// Port on which the server is receiving email
MAIL_PORT=587 
// The username with which to make authentification on the mail server
MAIL_USERNAME=johndoe
// The password of the user
MAIL_PASSWORD=feaeda91d
// If the server is using encryption you can set it here
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

Comment: My office mail link is `http://mail.xxxx.in/` (here xxxx is my office name).. Can i use this for **MAIL_DRIVER** and **MAIL_HOST**

Comment: You can use It  only for **MAIL_HOST** and you must remove **http://** which come before the host name. Related to MAIL_DRIVER you can still using **smtp** which is generaly the driver which is used by most Mail Server. Unless you are using another specificaly.